# Generics with runtime Types

Tags: c#, reflection, json.net, moq

I am using Moq and want to mock an interface which inherits from ICloneable. I am using Newtonsoft.Json to serialise and deserialise my object to a cloned instance.

The interface:

```
 public interface ITestInterface : ICloneable
 {
     int Number { get; set; }
     string Text { get; set; }
     string MethodCallResult { get; set; }
     void CallMe();
 }
```

I am trying to use generics to convert the object but I cannot know the actual runtime type of the proxy which Moq will provide.

Using the debugger through the following method I can see that the runtime type is a proxy but the type of the generic 'T' is the interface, ITestInterface, which cannot be serialised. How can I use the *real* runtime type with generics to serialize/deserialize these objects? I would just pass the type as a parameter but I do not know it at compile time.

```
private object CreateClone<T>(T item)
        where T : class
    {
        var realRuntimeType = item.GetType(); //is a proxy created by Moq inheriting from the interface
        var itemAsSerializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( item );
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( itemAsSerializedString ); //wont work, tries to instantiate interface
    }
```

Usage (note that the generic parameter is inferred, not explicit):

```
var mock = new Mock<ITestInterface>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Clone()).Returns(CreateClone(mock.Object));
```

Exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Could not create an instance of type Processus.Tests.ITestInterface. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: "I would just pass the type as a parameter but I do not know it at compile time." - will you know it as a `Type` at runtime?

Comment: Yes, in that I can call GetType() on my object reference and it returns a Type object for the *real * runtime type - but I can't use that as a generic type parameter at compile time. And allowing generics to infer the Type at compile time, as above, is taking the compile time Type of the reference, which is of the interface.

Comment: Mixing generics and reflection is *usually* very hard and expensive, but there is a cute trick: use the DLR. If you have `dynamic obj = yourObject`, then `CreateClone(obj)` is a *runtime optimized* (meaning: involves reflection, but the 2nd, 3rd etc calls are very very cheap) way of making it flip into generics with the right `T` for the occasion...

Comment: Aha! Getting a different error now but onlybecause the type doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, so that's a separate issue. This solves the generic type issue. Thank you! :)